# jQuery .dialog method fails when trying to set a title with accents

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, razorengine

I want to modify at runtime an html page title, I am using the RazonEngineProcessor with a cshtml template based in a widged built with jQuery. The title is changed this way:

```
$("#ValDlgTitle").dialog('option', 'title', '@ViewBag.Model.Title');
```

I have found that, if the title has accents, the world is not shown correctly, for example, it says `Mensajes de Validaci&amp;#243;n` instead of `Mensajes de Validación`.

The template also builds some dynamic tables by passing values from the ViewBag and in that case accents are shown correctly, for example this line:

```
<tr><td><span style="color:#f78955">@valWarn.SeverityLabel:&nbsp;&nbsp;@valWarn.TaskName&nbsp;-&nbsp;@valWarn.ValidationComment</span></td></tr>
```

Can become:

```
Aviso:  Solicitud (Dirección-General) - Campo de búsqueda nulo
```

Is there any way to change the title to some string with accents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed by using .html instead of .dialog.

```
$("#ValDlgTitle").html('@ViewBag.Model.Title');
```

Another way this can be done is by referencing the title CSS class instead of referencing an Id.

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar .ui-dialog-title").html('@ViewBag.Model.Title');
```